# How can I use the execute and particle commands together to make particles appear on the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make particles with the `/execute` command, but I do not know the syntax.

I want to summon flame particles rounded around a player. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi! We're a good place to ask for help, but please don't ask us to do your homework for you. We can give you advice on how to fix specific problems with your command, but we can't be expected to write the entire program for you from scratch. Have you done some past trials that didn't work, or researched but are still confused? Showing what you've achieved up to this point will give us a starting point that we can work off of.

Comment: Sorry for bad english.
I think you did not get what I mean.
I mean I need an example to continue this style.
Can you help?

Comment: What's important is that you've at least tried to help yourself before posting here, either by doing some research or by trying out some things that you think might work but didn't. Have you tried asking the almighty Google for help? We can't help you until we've seen evidence that you've tried to help yourself.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I searched everywhere but, bc that I do not understand english very well and the definitions were very confusing.
I could not find out what is align or anchor or ....../I just tryed my best.!

Comment: The gamepedia is probably the best place to go for this - also you shouldn’t need to align or anchor (I don’t think) for this. If you have a more specific question about syntax or something else that would be a better question. Hope you figure this out!

Comment: @Penguin as I said I could not undrsatnd what does gamepedia said >:

Comment: @Y.R What's your primary language? The Minecraft Wiki is available in many other languages, so we may be able to direct you to the one in a language you are more fluent in.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 My primary land is persian

Answer (score 0):

If you need help getting the particles, I just summon an area effect cloud, the link below is a generator for it.
https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/#!33816

The way I would go about this, there are probably other ways, is to run
`execute at @p run summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Particle:crit ,Radius:1f,Duration:1}`

To break down what is happening, the execute at tells where the summon command should run. This only works for entities, in this case the nearest player (@p), once the execute has determined where to do this from, the command summons the area effect cloud at the coords (~ ~ ~). In the braces ({}) is where the type of particle and other nbt data are determined. The generator I linked to can help you figure this out.

I hope that helped and made sense.